# Opening Help writings log in Application console

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-kepler

I created one RCP application, in that application I'm including help module.

When I open help then in my application console lots of log is writing by help. See the below image for more details:

[image]

Is there is any way to hide these logs from console. what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the RCP in the image has Jetty logging set to DEBUG level.
Since Eclipse Help is using embedded Jetty, the DEBUG messages are logged to stderr, in this case the console.

If you don't use a logging framework, you can disable these messages by setting

```
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=WARN
```

to your RCP VM arguments.